# How to rename the column names in AWS RDS Data API?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-rds-data-service

I just showed the data from SQL, and it is returned as a JSON ExecuteStatement.
The response is like this:

```
{
    "numberOfRecordsUpdated": 0,
    "records": [
        [
            {
                "isNull": 1
            },
            {
                "stringValue": "Example"
            },
            {
                "stringValue": "Example"
            },
            {
                "stringValue": "example@example.com"
            },
            {
                "isNull": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to change the values name, or the columns name.
Something like this:

```
first_name: example
second_name: example
email: example@example.com
```

The lambda function

```
const params{ = 

secretArn: 'arn:aws.....',
database: 'database name',
SQL: SELECT * FROM database name,
includeResultMetadata: true,
};

try {
   const dbResponse = await RDS.executeStatement(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback('Query Failed');
    }else {
       callback(null, datarecords)';
   }
}).promise();

console.log(dbResponse); // the response in json 

return dbResponse; //return the json code
```

I returned the JSON response with a lambda function using node.js
Is there a way how to modify the column's name?

Would appreciate any response
Thank u!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the SQL statement and the nodejs code that uses it, and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: O.Jones showed the lambda function